# MySQL Subquery returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, primary-key, subquery

I have a table namely tbl_plays. It has the following columns and data

```
id(PK)|    gameid    |    drawid    |   etc
----------------------------------------------
   1  |     1509     |      73      |   etc
```

I am running this simple query.

`SELECT id FROM tbl_play WHERE id = 1 OR gameid = 0`

This query is run as a subquery which returns the `id` column data to a variable.

Now my question, why do I get the error **SUBQUERY RETURNS MORE THAN ONE ROW** where as it returns only one row. In Workbench it returns an editable result-set, and myAdmin shows edit/delete buttons.

Does it have anything related to the fact that I am fetching a PK column data? If it does, then how can I over come this.

Regards

P.S: `id` column has all unique values.

Comment: What if one row matches the `id`, and another one matches the `gameid`?

Comment: All the values or row ID and GameID are unique. All values are greater than zero. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Why are you looking for the GameID then? You could do with just searching for the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the LIMIT clause

```
SELECT id FROM tbl_play WHERE id = 1 OR gameid = 0 LIMIT 1;
```

This is an oversimplified answer.

If there is a row with PK=1, you find it.

If not, a full table scan may ensue because of gameid not being indexed.

You are better off splitting the query with a UNION. Perhaps, like this:

```
SELECT id FROM
(
    SELECT id FROM tbl_play WHERE id = 1
    UNION
    (SELECT id FROM tbl_play WHERE gameid = 0 LIMIT 1)
) A ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

Since I do not know the data, I cannot predict any performance results.

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2014-01-23 11:01 EST

The reason it works because of the goal I set for the query : Retrieve one value.

First look at the UNION

```
    SELECT id FROM tbl_play WHERE id = 1
    UNION
    (SELECT id FROM tbl_play WHERE gameid = 0 LIMIT 1)
```

The first SELECT can return at most one row.

The second SELECT can return at most one row because of the `LIMIT 1`.

In the worst case scenario, the UNION will have two rows.

Now look at the whole query:

```
SELECT id FROM
(
    SELECT id FROM tbl_play WHERE id = 1
    UNION
    (SELECT id FROM tbl_play WHERE gameid = 0 LIMIT 1)
) A ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

The outer part of the query will receive either 0, 1, or 2 rows.

Then, the part `ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` forces the outer query to choose the first value.

Comment: It works. :) Can you tell me the reason why this works?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain why my suggested query works.